# What's the easiest way to track exact time of a user ssh to another system

Tags: centos, ssh, syslog

env - centos/rhel
I have two systems. Bastion and DEV.

---

Bastion -

- Bastion has many individual users. (`apple`, `orange`... etc)
- Users can directly ssh to Bastion.

DEV -

- DEV has only one user. (`fruit`)
- Only Bastion users can ssh to DEV from Bastion.

Ultimately, I want to trace "who did what and when"

On DEV side, I can see someone logged in as `fruit` in /var/etc/secure and /var/etc/audit/audit.log, but not "by whom".

---

My question :
How do I collect the time when `apple` connected to DEV as `fruit` and what he did?

Comment: The ssh connections should be logged in one of the /var/log log files - messages maybe? I setup my ssh to log all ssh connections to /var/log/ssh.log. As for who did what when you need to turn on accounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple method would be to disable password logins and use key-based logins only.

That way you have the key named in `auth.log` and may simply match it to a user (e.g add the user name in the "comment" field of the `authorized_keys` file). With the login, you get a process ID that is also shown the at logout event.

```
$cat /var/log/auth.log
Jun 21 14:42:11 DEV sshd[26510]: Accepted publickey for apple from 1234:5678:90ab:cdef:1234:5678:90ab:cdef port 58888 ssh2: RSA SHA256:abcdefghIJKLMNOPQ/1234567890
Jun 21 14:47:57 DEV sshd[26510]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user apple


$cat /home/fruit/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa abcdefghIJKLMNOPQ/1234567890 apple@bastion
```

The rest of the monitoring is then a matter of setting up `audit`.

Comment: Thanks. This method was my first attempt but I gave up on it because all my users are using the same key as they were created with skell. Well... seems I have no other options.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a terrible answer (because `identd` is unreliable and easily faked and can expose information about your users when they connect to other systems), but in the old days people used `identd` for things like this.

You could run `identd` **on "bastion"** (with configuration and firewall rules to prevent access to port 113 from anywhere but "DEV" or your internal network).

`sshd` is usually compiled with `libwrap`, and `/etc/hosts.allow` **on DEV** can be configured to log the username reported by bastion's identd, with a rule like:

```
sshd : ALL : spawn = /usr/bin/logger -i --tag "sshd+identd" -p auth.notice "attempted login by %u@%h" &
```

That would result in lines like the following being logged:

```
Jun 21 14:13:33 DEV sshd+identd[2128678]: attempted login by apple@bastion
```

followed immediately by the usual sshd logs.

Note that this can cause delays (while the `identd` query is being made and timing out) for users logging in directly to DEV from other hosts that aren't running `identd` (e.g. client machines on your LAN) .

Note also that at the time the remote username is logged, it is still just an **attempted login** as it happens as soon as the connection is made, before sshd authenticates the login with password or public key.

I'm not sure what versions of `identd` are still being maintained on Centos, but AFAIK the only one still available on Debian is [oidentd](https://oidentd.janikrabe.com/).  It's a mostly-forgotten, obsolete technology that almost nobody uses any more (some IRC networks still use it and some IRC clients can optionally listen on port 113 and respond to `identd` requests).